# Softlayer getTags exclude tags with no devices

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have created several devices with a tag [dummy].

I then canceled these machines, so there are no longer any devices listed under the tag [dummy].

In a script, I call [getTags](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Tag) through Softlayer's Ruby API.

The list still includes the tag [dummy].

I apply an object mask to get reference counts for tags:

```
{"accountId"=>979273, "id"=>882895, "internal"=>0, "name"=>"dummy", "referenceCount"=>11}
```

The referenceCount is non-zero. The same is true for every other tag that no longer has devices. Is there any way for me to filter out tags that no longer have any devices assigned to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to filter this through API, you should try to do this in your code.

e.g:

> item["referenceCount"] == 0.

Comment: Yes, but the referenceCount itself appears incorrect, unless I'm misunderstanding something. In the example I gave, the 'dummy' tag has a referenceCount of 11, even though I have already canceled every VM instance with the dummy tag. Shouldn't the referenceCount be 0? Is it a bug that it is 11? Or does referenceCount refer to something other than the number of devices tagged 'dummy'?

Comment: It seems that **references** and **referenceCount** properties take in account the devices deleted, because they still have a relation with the tag, it seems a bug because there is no way to delete this, please submit a ticket for further assistance.

Comment: I've opened a ticket which has been passed to the dev team. The ticket's status hasn't changed since Oct 3, so odds are it is not high on their agenda. I'm going to accept this answer since the comment is correct and it appears to be a bug.

Comment: Thanks, an issue has been opened (it is still open), I think it will be fixed very soon, my apologies for the inconveniences